# Search name File in bat script

Tags: batch-file

I need to Search a file name in directory windows.

Example:

```
*Directory* 
D:\app\admin\DBSAUDE2\model_his_pep\
```

And inside this path, exists N files, example below:

```
PEP_121160.dmp
PEP_121130.dmp
```

I need to take this name, put in variable and use this name to move the file to FTP directory.

```
\sftp\variable1\PEP\variable2
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You stated that you need to search a file name, however you don't appear to have provided any information related to a file name search. With poor information the likely responses will also be poor, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45575849/edit) your question with better information.

Comment: `for`, `set`, `ren`/`rnfr` and `rnto`.